# Game theory and sharing

Tags: game-theory

What sort of mathematical knowledge is required for applying game theory specifically in relation to evaluating fairness in a shared resource environment?

One of the things I'd like to explore in my evaluation is the relation between fairness and efficiency. What is the impact of compromising a bit of fairness in order to achieve overall efficiency? Some sort of mathematical analysis to determine when it might be beneficial (and by how much) to co-operate or defect?

Could you please also suggest resources for self study in this regard?

I have referred to information presented here [Game theory - self study](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76096/game-theory-self-study/1624833#1624833)

Thanks

NCB

Comment: This is pretty broad brush.  When interesting problems arise that don't seem amenable to the usual tools (linear algebra, probability, differential equations), it motivates the introduction of new tools.  However much depends on having a good/real-world problem.

Comment: I am posting here for the first time and I couldn't find information on policies for starting a new thread when there is already an existing thread on the same topic. As such, I initially posted my question in an existing thread. I am now re-posting this question here as suggested. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  We aim to curate excellent content in the form of Questions and Answers covering every aspect of mathematics. (It's a work in progress.)  To promote learning, we seek questions that can be answered in reasonably concise and definitive terms.  It would be an improvement if you can narrow your request to a single problem involving sharing of resources, efficiency, etc.  See [ask].

Comment: Have you looked at the fair division literature?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_division  Then see what math you need to understand it. More generally, an awful lot of cooperative game theory can be thought of as fairness. As for the math, John Rawls And Robert Nozick made quite a splash with no math, while A.K Sen was more formal.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't looked at fair division and I am reading now. The problem I wish to solve is bandwidth allocation. I will need to mathematically come up with some analysis and then incorporate the best option into an algorithm.

Comment: @Trurl, 

The sharing is broadly between two groups, where one group will always be present and the other group can vary in their number randomly. 

Consider a home Internet connection that is shared between the owner and the tenants. The owner will always be at the house and the number of tenants sharing the house with him varies depending on the time of the year and the duration of their lease. When there are no tenants, the owner is able to make full use of the connection, but when there are others in the house, the owner has to share with them equally.

Comment: This is a simplified analogy/example but in the actual scenario, it is difficult to accurately identify whether there are any tenants and if so how many. The algorithm also cannot predict the lease duration. Sometimes, a tenant might stay for a very short duration (say, for a day to a week) during which the owner is not obligated to modify his usage patterns (because the cost of the algorithm to constantly vary the usage is high).

Comment: I should have added earlier.... If the owner fails to share fairly with (all) the tenants (long-term ones), then the owner as well as the existing and the new tenants will incur a penalty. So it is a bit of a gamble to predict how long each tenant will stay and whether it is worth changing the usage patterns to accommodate a new user.